# Three.js: how to keep sprite text size unchanged when zooming

Tags: canvas, three.js, sprite

In three.js, when the mouse is zoomed, the text will be magnified and reduced accordingly.

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial ( { map: texture, transparent:false } );
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
```

How do you keep the text size from changing when the mouse is zoomed?

Comment: Are you using three.js r.63? If not, please upgrade. Do you mean mouse zoom? When the mouse zooms, the sprite changes size by default.

Comment: Yes, I am using r63, your understanding is correct, there are ways to achieve it?

Comment: I want this effect：When the mouse zooms,  he size of the sprite unchanged。。。

Comment: think you very much!!!! I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My default, sprites scale according to their distance from the perspective camera -- just like other objects do.

If you do not want them to scale, you can overlay a second scene of sprites, rendered with an orthographic camera. See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html.

It is called a "heads-up-display", or HUD.

EDIT: `SpriteMaterial` now has a `sizeAttenuation` property, which you can optionally set to `false`. Default is `true`.

three.js r.96

Comment: HUD？？ I am sorry！I can not understand that what HUD is。。can it solve this problem？

Comment: by the way, when use a perspective camera，it is possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: 1. HUD: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HUD_(video_gaming) 2. You use a perspective camera to render your scene, and then on top of that you use an orthographic camera to render the sprites -- just like in the example I referenced.

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this with a perspective camera you can set the sprite scale factor according to the ratio between distance of the sprite from camera and some "virtual distance".

In the example below, virtual_d is used to set a fixed virtual "distance" between the sprite and the camera before rendering

```
var scale = sprite.position.distanceTo(camera.position) / virtual_d;
scale = Math.min(you_max_scale_value, Math.max(you_min_scale_value, scale));

sprite.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
```

However if you don't want any distortion, eg in the borders when the field of view is large, use an orthographic camera instead.