# Three.js Update Child without inheriting everything from Parent

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a **Three.js** Scene where I have a simple `THREE.Mesh` I call `cube`. I want to add a `label` to `cube` that always displays above `cube` (so in the positive `y` direction, given that `y` is `up`).

Therefor, the `label` should inherit the `position` of the `cube`, but not the `rotation` or `scale`. I want the label to always be same size relative to the `camera` I am looking through.

Given that I already have initialized `cube`, I now create the `label`:

```
var label = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
label.position.set(0, 1, 0); // above cube
```

Then I add the `label` to the `cube` to inherit its `position`:

```
cube.add(label);
```

Fair enough. However, when I `rotate` or `scale` the `cube`, the label goes with it relative to the `cube`.

**I would like the `label` to stay above the `cube`, remain the same size, ignore both `rotation` and `scale`, but inherit `position` of the `cube`.**

How would I achieve this effect?

Comment: I think that you want is a sprite. http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Objects/Sprite

Comment: @Radio Thank you, that solves part of my problem already. I was not aware of this feature. The label is now indeed always facing the camera. However, ``rotation`` and ``scale`` still affect the ``label``. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I recommend then that you use a div. You can convert an object's position to it's screen position. Use the screen position to move your div. See the r.75 (the latest I could find) example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection

Comment: I forgot about this, see the last answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396150/three-js-how-to-keep-sprite-text-size-unchanged-when-zooming