# 2D text size in ThreeJS

Tags: 3d, three.js, 2d

I'm building a 3D environment using ThreeJS in which the camera is at a fixed position, but users can "look around/move the camera" using pointer lock controls.

Objects appear at random places in the 3D environment. I put a certain word next to each object. The word is a 2D sprite since it should always face the user, even if he starts looking around.

This is the code I use for the text sprite:

```
function makeTextSprite(message, parameters) {
  var fontface = parameters.hasOwnProperty("fontface") ? parameters["fontface"] : "Arial";
  var fontsize = 65;
  var borderThickness = 0;

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.font = fontsize + "px " + fontface;
  var metrics = context.measureText(message);
  var textWidth = metrics.width;

  context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + backgroundColor.r + "," + backgroundColor.g + "," + backgroundColor.b + "," + backgroundColor.a + ")";
  context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + borderColor.r + "," + borderColor.g + "," + borderColor.b + "," + borderColor.a + ")";

  context.lineWidth = borderThickness;
  roundRect(context, borderThickness / 2, borderThickness / 2, (textWidth + borderThickness) * 1.1, fontsize * 1.4 + borderThickness, 8);

  context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + textColor.r + ", " + textColor.g + ", " + textColor.b + ", 1.0)";
  context.fillText(message, borderThickness, fontsize + borderThickness);

  var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  texture.needsUpdate = true;

  var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    map: texture,
    useScreenCoordinates: false
  });
  var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
  sprite.scale.set(0.5 * fontsize, 0.25 * fontsize, 0.75 * fontsize);
  return sprite;
}
```

This works fine, but I want the text to have the same size, always, as a percentage of the browser width, no matter where the object is. 
In the code above, the text always has the same size, but it *appears* smaller when it's put further away from the camera, which I don't want.

Anyone knows how I could achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll find answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28875549/5487053)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `sprite.position.distanceTo(camera.position)`seems to return "0" at all times, unfortunately.

Comment: Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40452050/4045502) with a jsfiddle example